# How do I share NFS mounts over zeroconf?

Tags: nfs, avahi, zeroconf

I would like to advertise my NFS shares via Avahi so that I can just browse from multiple machines without having to set it all up, especially when guests come over and I want something automagic.

I am aware most clients will need extra packages (Like `nfs-common`) installed for it to work. The ideal solution will include instructions for clients as well (if any).

Comment: This question is best suited for stackoverflow, you would need to developt both a server and client service, the server service would run on the nfs server broadcasting the availability of your "custom nfs" service (using avahai/zeroconf) and providing a list of available nfs exports. The client service would need to identify available "custom nfs" servers, get the shares list and mount them.

Comment: Wait, it's not possible to just advertise NFS shares with zeroconf and have them seen by the file manager?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer to [question 18933](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18933) actually included an answer for NFS shares (although the question did not explicitly mention NFS):
Create a service description file (e.g. `nfs.service`) in `/etc/avahi/services` with the following content:

```
<service-group>
  <name replace-wildcards="yes">NFS share on %h</name>
  <service>
    <type>_nfs._tcp</type>
    <port>2049</port>
    <txt-record>path=/path/to/someshare</txt-record>
  </service>
</service-group>
```

The port 2049 requires you to use the `insecure` option in the `/etc/exports` file, though.

Then it should be possible to use your file manager, navigate to "Networks" and access your share. Unfortunately, The GNOME file manager does *not* provide support for NFS at the moment ([Launchpad Bug #29263](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gvfs/+bug/29263), thanks to João Pinto for pointing this out) and the NFS support in the KDE file manager is broken (<s>[KDE bug #184997](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=184997)</s> Now fixed) as well…

Comment: Please note that Nautilus does not discover NFS shares.

Comment: This is good to know in case someday they fix the bug João is talking about.

Comment: @João: Thanks for pointing this out, I should have followed the link you posted... I updated my answer.

Comment: When I  click the advertised share in Mint 18, VLC opens?

Answer (score 2):

NFS advertised shares are not handled by gnome-vfs at this time, there is a bug report requesting it:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/gnome-vfs/+bug/29263